# Using grepl beyond a 'this or that' condition

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl

I have a dataframe of the following pattern:
tibble [9 x 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)

```
 $ Date: chr [1:9] "Tuesday 4 October 2022" "Wednesday 5 October 2022" "Thursday 6 October 2022" "Friday 7 October 2022:"
 $ SIC       : chr [1:9] "01500" "01610" "01629" "01630"
```

I'd like to use grepl to convert the 'SIC' to its appropriate classification in words as a new column named "Type".
01500 = "Mixed farming", 01610 = "Support activities for crop production", 01629 = "    Support activities for animal production (other than farm animal boarding and care) n.e.c.", 01630 =    Post-harvest crop activities"

Using grepl, I've got as far as doing:

```
df$Type <- ifelse(grepl("01500", df$SIC), "Mixed farming", "Other")
```

And that ofc only works for one specific case. Does anyone know how to extend it out to far more conditions?

Comment: Use `dplyr`'s `case_when`, not `grepl`. This is not about pattern matching, it's about exact equality, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where a named array (the R equivalent of a dictionary) works really well. Note the use of quotes on the names (this is necessary because they are numeric)

```
dict <- c(
  "01500" = "Mixed farming", 
  "01610" = "Support activities for crop production", 
  "01629" = "Support activities for animal production (other than farm animal boarding and care) n.e.c.", 
  "01630" = "Post-harvest crop activities"
)

df$Type <- dict[df$SIC]
```